# Creating a punctuation vector in R

Tags: r, string

I am trying to create a vector in R that includes punctuation marks.
This is the code that I have right now:

```
punctuation <- c(".", ",", "!", "?", "'", """,  "(", ")", " ", "-", ";", ":")
```

The error keeps coming from the three " in a row: """
I need to include " as a value in my string, but cannot figure out how to do it without getting an error.

I have tried adding spaces around it and introducing different symbols, but everything keeps creating an error.
Ideally, I should get a vector that produces something like
"." "," "!" "?" "'" """  "(" ")" " " "-" ";" ":"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try wrapping that element in single quotation marks e.g. :

```r
punctuation <- c(".", ",", "!", "?", "'", '"', "(", ")", " ", "-", ";", ":")
```

Comment: That fixed the error, but put the symbol / instead of ", so I'm not sure how to get " to be in the final vector: "."  ","  "!"  "?"  "'"  "\"" "("  ")"  " "  "-"  ";"  ":"

Comment: It will print in the console as `\"`. Using the \ in R is a way of escaping characters.  You could alternatively write `punctuation <- c(".", ",", "!", "?", "'", "\"", "(", ")", " ", "-", ";", ":") `. 

It will appear printed in e.g. plots as just a single quotation mark

Comment: Use `cat(punctuation)` to see the values without the default escaping of special characters used by `print()`